# For cycle: calculation inside cells

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I have this line of code:

```
clear MUCV
 for c = 1:size(CVV,2)
     r = 1:size(CVV,1);
     MUCV(r,c) = (round(100*median(abs(CVV{c}(CCC{c}>0.8))))/100);
 end
```

Where `CVV` and `CCC` are two equal matrices containing cells, and I have to apply that calculation to each cell.

The problem is that, in this *for* cycle, the calculation is done only for the first row and then copies in `MUCV` the same row many times as specified in `r`.

If I add `{r and c}` in the following it gives me an error.

```
MUCV(r,c) = (round(100*median(abs(CVV{r,c}(CCC{r,c}>0.8))))/100);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the error message and an idea why get this error. It would be helpful if you added some test data to play around with and to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to extract all the elements that match the constraint `CCC{c}>0.8` from `CVV{c}`. I reckon MATLAB will not allow you to do that in a one-step fashion and you must do it in separate steps.

The problem is with `r`. You have to create a nested *for* loop in order to scan every element according to indices `c` and `r`, like this:

```
for c = 1:size(CVV,2)
    for r = 1:size(CVV,1);
        % do something
    end
end
```

But you must edit the inner line since, again, I reckon it won't work. Maybe try something like:

```
for c = 1:size(CVV,2)
    for r = 1:size(CVV,1);
        SelectedCVV=CVV{r,c};
        MUCV(r,c) = (round(100*median(abs(SelectedCVV(CCC{r,c}>0.8))))/100);
    end
end
```

You can as well reach the same results by using `cellfun()` instead of the nested loops. This function allows you to perform the same function to each cell in a cell array. In your case, you should use something like

```
MUCV=cellfun(@(x,y) round(100*median(abs(x(y>0.8))))/100,CVV,CCC)
```

where `x` and `y` are the single cells in (respectively) `CVV` and `CCC`.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I want to extract from CVV all the elements that have CCC >0.8.

I have added the nested for cycle, but still I cannot think how to do add as you suggested separated steps in order to have all the values.

Comment: I have updated the post. However a brief description regarding CVV and CCC and what the singular cell contains would be nice. If I understood correctly every cell in CVV and CCC contains a vector

Comment: Actually, thank you! Now it works: this is the code,

clear MUCV
 for c = 1:size(CVV,2)
    for r = 1:size(CVV,1);
     MUCV(r,c) = (round(100*median(abs(CVV{r,c}(CCC{r,c}>0.8))))/100);
    end
 end